# How to obtain CGPathRef from a view whose mask has been set to that CGPathRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

I have a view whose mask I had set earlier in some method, now I want to extract the CGPathRef which was the shape of the mask without having nothing at all, just the view with mask. How do I do that?

```
CAShapeLayer* maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                maskLayer = (CAShapeLayer* )myView.layer.mask;
                CGPathRef x = maskLayer.path;
```

tried this, didn't work.

Comment: check if maskLayer is not nil

Comment: yeah, that's where the problem is, the mask is applied,"myView.layer.mask;"   isn't nil, but the assignment isn't working, maskLayer is empty.

Comment: BTW.: The initialization of `maskLayer` in the first line is totally needless.

Comment: @SudhanshuMonga that's your issue its seems that myView.layer.mask is not a CAShapeLayer, so you can't get the path from it, i will test in a example your case scenario and check if can be done

Comment: @ReinierMelian is there a way around to get the path then? I just need the path.

Comment: are you sure that your layer.mask is a CAShapeLayer? add this line  `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass(myView.layer.mask.class));` this should print `CAShapeLayer` @SudhanshuMonga, let me know

Comment: actually it is not, it's CALayer, so I guess there is no way to get the mask's path?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of a `CALayer` if its a `CAShapeLayer` which is a `CALayer` subclass so if your `myView.layer.mask` is not `CAShapeLayer` object you can't get the `CGPath`  you can check if its the right class making a check

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass(myView.layer.mask.class));
```

this must print

> CAShapeLayer

Comment: unfortunately it prints CALayer.